# Making minimum number of partitions of a set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, algorithms

Let us consider a set in which every element has an ordered pair of natural number (x,y)( Each pair is distinct) associated with it. Let us define a partition of a set to be consisting of elements such that  one of the numbers from the pair (i.e either x or y is same throughout the partition ) . We have to partition the set into minimum number of components such that union of all the components is the set itself. How can we find the minimum number of components into which  set can be partitioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If either all x or all y values in the set are distinct, you are done. Otherwise:

1. Construct a bipartite graph with vertices in A representing the values of x and vertices in B representing the values of y.
2. Each edge represents the ordered pair. You need to find the minimum vertex cover for a bipartite graph. This can be done by Konig's theorem, Wikipedia gives a good explanation of the algorithm.